# Sequelize, multer, nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, multer

I currently have a model that includes the following:

```js
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
}, name: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
}, images: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
}
```

I'm storing the file name of the images as a string on POSTGRES by using

//POST METHOD

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  MODEL.create({
    images: JSON.stringify(req.files.map(file => file.filename))
  })
})
```

when i try it without the JSON.stringify, i get an error saying images cannot be an array or object (problem 1)

My 2nd problem is now when I try to access the image in my get request I want to change the image from being a filename to a URL and thumbnail URL as below

url: `${baseUrl}${image}_full.jpg`

thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${image}_thumb.jpg`

Comment: What do you mean by `from being a string to an object`? the purpose of this new get request is to download the images in that way: `${baseUrl}${image}_[....].jpg`?
If you just need to download search for serve static content on express

Comment: hi sheldon, my images datatype is a STRING, in my post method using the create method i pass req.files.map((file) => ({ fileName: file.filename })) an error occurs saying images cannot be an array or an object. how do i solve this?

Comment: and when i use JSON.stringify, this is my output images:[{\"fileName\":\"95aa17801d5b810eb9.png\"}]